# Calculate unique rows based on conditional count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

From the table below, I want to calculate the number of occurrences of score 0.0000 when the status is not 3. In addition, I want to return unique rows by question ID.

I've tried COUNT and Group by clauses, but I couldn't get very far. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
question_id question_desc   status  class_id    score
650               DE           3    1          0.0000
650               DE           2    1          1.0000
651             ADELA          2    1          1.0000
651             ADELA          2    1          1.0000
652               AE           2    1          1.0000
652               AE           2    1          1.0000
653               AP           2    1          0.0000
653               AP           2    1          1.0000
```

...transformed to...

```
question_id question_desc   count 
650               DE           0
651             ADELA          0
652               AE           0
653               AP           1
```

Comment: I don't even know what I want to do is possible or not. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case` to count only rows that meet a condition:

```
select  question_id
,       question_desc
,       count(case when score = 0 and status <> 3 then 1 end) as [count]
from    YourTable
group by
        question_id
,       question_desc
```

That's assuming `score` is an exact numeric type, like `decimal`.  If it's an approximate numeric type, like `float` or `real`, use:

```
,       count(case when abs(score) < 0.00005 and status <> 3 then 1 end) as [count]
```

Comment: I believe you forgot the status != 3 in the case statement there.

Comment: @Andomar, thank you. I did try the case, but also had the else which was preventing the table from returning what I wanted it to.